# A continuous bijection between two complete metric spaces that is not a homeomorphism.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

> Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are two metric spaces and $f: X\to Y$ be a continuous bijection.
>
> Now my **question** is does the completeness of $X$ and $Y$ implies $f$ to be a Homeomorphism?

**My idea**. First of all I try to prove $f$ to be a **closed** map assuming $X$ and $Y$ be a complete metric space. But this idea didn't work.

I know if $X$ is given to be **compact** then whether or not $Y$ complete given initially  $f$ becomes a homeomorphism. But that is not the case here. So I try to find a **counter example**.

I take $Y=\Bbb{R}$ and try to choose $X$ to be a **non compact** but closed subset of $\Bbb{R}$ (and  $\Bbb{R}^2$) but the problem is in that situation the bijections I found was **not continuous**. Also I cannot found any example beyond the metric spaces $\Bbb{R}$ or $\Bbb{R}^2$ as my $X$.

Can any one help me to figure out how to construct an counter example here. Thanks ...

Comment: For the record, if $X$ is compact then there is no "whether *or not* $Y$ is complete", because $Y$ *will* be complete just by the fact that there is a continuous bijection.

Comment: Yes of course.....

Comment: Between linear normed spaces any such bijective linear map will be a homeomorphism because of the open mapping theorem which holds for complete linear spaces.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The identity map from $\mathbb  R$ with discrete metric into $\mathbb  R$ with usual metric  is a continuous bijection which is not  a homeomorphism. Both spaces are complete.

Answer (score 18):

First, observe that $[0,1)$ is homeomorphic to $[0,\infty)$ and clearly $[0,\infty)$ is complete because is a closed subset of a complete metric space ($\mathbb{R}$). Take $f:[0,\infty)\to[0,1)$ such homeomorphism. Consider the function $g:[0,1)\to\mathbb{S}^1$ defined by $g(x)=(\cos(2\pi x),\sin(2\pi x))$. It's not to hard to prove that $g$ is continuous and biyective. Thus, $g\circ f:[0,\infty)\to\mathbb{S}^1$ is continuous and biyective function and the domain is complete but $g\circ f$ is not an homeomorrphism because $\mathbb{S}^1$ is compact and $[0,\infty)$ isn't.

Comment: Very nice example... thank you so much